# ESRI ArcGIS: FDO_E_VERSION_REDEFINED - .NET Application

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-10.6, workspace

I have an application for ArcGIS 10.6 which it's built as follows:

- A class called `Geodatabase`, which implements the interface `IDisposable`

Inside the class, there are some methods, like:

- `VersionExists` that uses `IVersionedWorkspace.FindVersion` to check if version exists
- `startEditOperation` and `stopEditOperation` functions, which use I`WorkspaceEdit.StartEditOperation` or `StopEditOperation`
- `stopEditing` that uses `IWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(saveEdits)`

Also, a function called:

- `openWorkspace` that uses `IWorkspaceFactory` with a new `SdeWorkspaceFactoryClass`, then it opens the Oracle SQL instance with the version that should be everytime "SDE.DEFAULT"

The application does also other things, but the problem here it's that after X hours of running, when using the `IWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(saveEdits)` inside the logs it says: "FDO_E_VERSION_REDEFINED" like if something changed in the version the application was writing / reading, so it's not able to save the edits made.

The question is, even if it's a disposable class, how can I avoid this error and "reload" the version that changed?

Is there a way to close the workspace? Or to solve this error?